# Smoothing the curve

Tags: matlab, plot

Below is my code for the plot. How to make the plot more smoother.

```
len1 = [25, 250, 500, 750, 1000];
for k1 = 1:length(len1)
    standard_deviation1(k1) = std(resdphs(1:5000, len1(k1)));
end

f10 = [110, 100, 90, 80, 70];
figure(3),plot(f10, standard_deviation1);xlabel('frequency'); ylabel('standarddev');
```

grid[image]

Comment: [`smooth`](http://mathworks.com/help/curvefit/smooth.html)?

Comment: take the moving average maybe?

Comment: i means, if you observe the plot, it has many corners. So it shoud be without corners. At the corner there shoud be smooth curve.

Comment: ahh ok. Thanks GameofThrows and Hbaderts for your comments.

Comment: matlab is plotting what you are asking it to plot, so if you want it to be smoother, try taking the running average, which will make is smoother

Comment: Your code and that plot don't correspond to each other.  Specifically the `x` values are plotting `f10` which range from 110 to 70, yet your `x` axis in your plot range from 0 to 5000.

Comment: For moving average to work, you'd also have to interpolate between each of your keypoints.  From the plot, it looks like each point is spaced by 500 units and so moving average probably won't help you here unless the density of the data is significantly increased.

Comment: ahh ok.. how shoud i proceed?

Comment: @MayankLakhani - Let me write an answer.  Hold on.

Comment: No problem.  Check my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you can first try to apply a [moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) to your data which applies local smoothing to overlapping windows in your data.  However, for this to be successful, you must have a higher point density to achieve good smoothing.  Currently, your plot only has a few points uniformly spaced at 500 units and so moving average will significantly alter the way the plot looks.  I'll show you an example soon.

Let's get back to the method at hand.  First, apply linear interpolation between each of the points to get a higher point density.  After you apply linear interpolation, you can apply the moving average operation with [`conv`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html).  However, what will happen is that in between your keypoints will exist artificial data that isn't representative of your problem.  I'd also like to mention that this plot is for aesthetic purposes and the data in between the keypoints should not be used for any critical decisions.

If you simply want to plot the points, consider not using `plot` and using [`stem`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stem.html) instead.  In any case,  use [`interp1`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) as the base method for interpolating in between the keypoints.  Once you do that, you can apply a moving average by convolution - specifically, use a kernel that has a small amount of filter taps that are all equally weighted.  Something like a 5-tap window or 7-tap window may suffice.

Using the variables that you declared above:

```
%// Specify number of total points
num_points = 300;

%// Specify moving average window
move_size = 7;

%// Specify interpolated y coordinates
xpts = linspace(min(f10), max(f10), num_points);
out = interp1(f10, standard_deviation1, xpts, 'linear');

%// Apply moving average
kernel = (1/move_size)*(ones(1,move_size));
out_smooth = conv(out, kernel, 'same');

%// Also apply moving average on the raw data itself for demonstration
out_smooth_raw = conv(standard_deviation1, kernel, 'same');

%// Plot everything
plot(f10, standard_deviation1, f10, out_smooth_raw, 'x-', xpts, out_smooth);
legend('Original Data', 'Smoothed Data - Raw', 'Smoothed Data - Interpolated');
```

Let's do this with some example data:

```
f10 = 0 : 500 : 5000;
rng(123); %// Set seed for reproducibility
standard_deviation1 = rand(1,numel(f10));
```

Using the above data and with the above code, we get this plot:

[image]

As you can see, applying a moving average on your data without interpolation significantly alters the data because of the resolution.  If you apply interpolation first, then apply a moving average, you will see that you get a somewhat better representation of your original data with the corners smoothed.  Bear in mind that the data at the beginning and at the end of the smoothened result will be meaningless as you would be taking the moving average of windows with zeros padded into the data to allow the calculations to work.

Comment: Why did you choose your `move_size` to be 7?

Comment: @christylynn002 experimentation. 7 seemed the best looking plot given the data. I tried a bunch of them. Choose a value that makes the most sense to you and also makes your plot look nice.